# How do I add a static link to a jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How do I embed a static URL link to the heading of my jasper reports so that when I click the company logo (or text) at the top of every HTML report, it will open our website in a browser and take me to my company home page.

I am using Jasper Report Studio 6.2.1 and hosting the reports on Jasper Server 6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference">
  <reportElement x="5" y="95" width="300" height="15"/>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">"  >> Click here to go to www.google.com"</textFieldExpression>
  <hyperlinkReferenceExpression>"http://www.google.com
</hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    </textField>
```